# Parent Class method is getting called before child class method

Tags: java, oop, gwt

I am facing a problem something like shadowing in Java. I have the following code:

```
public abstract class AsyncCallback<T> implements com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback<T>{
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught){
     try{
        throw caught;
     }catch(){

     }//various catch blocks
     .
     .
     catch(Throwable e){
         onError();
     }
  }

  public void onError() {
        //print something
  }

  abstract public void retry();
}
```

now I call a rpc call with the following syntax:

```
rpc.callAnyMethod(param, new AsyncCallback<SomeClass>(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SomeClass class) {
                setSomeClass(class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                try {
                    throw caught;
                } catch (ClientException e) {
                    if (e.getMessage().equals(sometoken)) {
                        //redirect to a link                    
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    retry();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void retry() {
                //call the method again.
            }
});
```

But the problem is that the method in the parent class XYZ is printing from onError() function first and then redirecting to the link i want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that it's not good practice to use exceptions as flow control.

Comment: Since you create an anonymous `AsyncCallback`, how would your XYZ class be implied in this code? Did you set a default Handler?

Comment: sorry kindly check the code now... :)

Comment: According to the code you posted, onError(..) is only called from onFailure in the parent class. In the anonymous inner class you override this method, without calling onError(). Therefore I don't see how onError can ever be called in this scenario.

Comment: It is getting called from onFailure from the parent class itself.

Comment: @Sourabh: but you override this method completely... Your new callback class never calls onError. I suppose you forgot to include some addditional relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Redesign your class hierarchy, that you don't overwrite/implicitly call concrete behavior - it is a common source for problems concerning inheritance hierarchies, when behavior is overwritten/extended/called by `super.method()` - to speak in words of Checkstyle, methods of classes should either be final (no overwriting allowed), abstract or empty (overwriting allowed).

**EDIT** One common pattern to avoid this behavior is the template method pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Okay so if this pattern is to be followed then I should not print anything in the onError method .... and what about the try catch blocks in the onFailure method?

Comment: I am not calling super.method explicitly though. So I don't know why will it get called from an anonymous object creation?

Comment: I can't mind-debug your code, but this implicit behavior overwrite is a common source of mistakes. You could check which statement of your inheriting class calls the wrong method in the parent class and change your posting.